# flexbox row and column ul li menu for safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

```
nav {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-pack: center
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    //border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    //border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #feaa38;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F5F5F5), to(#feaa38));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #feaa38;
} 
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:-999em;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width:100%;
}








nav ul li:hover > ul{
    top: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    background: #b56906;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000 !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
nav ul li ul li ul{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover > ul{
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}


nav ul li:Last-child {
    border-right: none;
}


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            adasdasdasda
            <ul>
                <li>
                    12321321321
                 <ul>
                <li>
               12adas4asfsafds321321321
                </li>
                <li>
                    56345sdfdsfdsfdssd453543
                </li>
            </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    56345453543
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            fasffasf
        </li>
        <li>
            asdasdas
            <ul>
                <li>
                    12321321321
                </li>
                <li>
                    56345453543
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my code for css on menu i am adding dynamic menu so i used flex box to make the width uniform even if i add dynamic menu sub menu and another sub menu the problem is when i tried it on sarafi it is not doing ok.But for chrome ie and mozilla it is ok. What seems to be different for safari that it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just changed my nav ul to this and it worked

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
    -moz-box-lines: multiple;
    -o-box-lines: multiple;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -o-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: i tested it in safari it worked for me mate when i check the about safari it shows me 5.1.7(7534.57.2) please let me know if this is the same as yours. if not then lets find a way to make it work for you. @duccom

Comment: you can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/5t9r69s9/ and open it on safari it works for me let me know if it works for you

Comment: thanks, worked for me in Safari on iPad, was all bunched up to the left